# Update Value via Store Procedure using IF statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create my first store procedure where if @ad1 (select address1 from address) = '' then run my store procedure to update @ad1 whatever @adnew is.

My SP:

```
    @Ad1 nvarchar(50), @adNew nvarchar(50)
AS
Select address1 from Address
where address1=@Ad1
Update Address
Set @Ad1 = @adNew
```

My query would be something along the lines of:

```
If
(Select Count(*)from Address where Address1 = '') > 15
exec scUpdateAddress1 @ad1 = '', @Adnew = 'BLANK'
Else
Print 'Not Enough Records to Update'
```

I have a feeling its second statement which is causing the issue, but I can't seem to fathom it out.

Many Thanks 
Sam

Comment: What is the issue ? And also you have to use `begin` and `end` if your `if` statement spans multiple lines, as I see it you are executing the `scUpdateAddress1` regardless of the result of the expression `(Select Count(*)from Address where Address1 = '') > 15`.

Comment: i don't agree to  Mihail Stancescus statement that begin/end is needed ... there's only one statement to be executed if the condition is true so wrapping it in begin/end is optional

Comment: @MihailStancescu I want to be able to run the procedure that whatever = `@adnew` it updates `@ad1` (depending what `@ad1` was originally)

I want `@adNew` to replcae whatever `@ad1` has (depending if `@ad1` meets the if statements true requirements)

Hope that wasn't too confusing.

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn you are right, there is only a `if` statement and I'm sorry about that, I got a bit confused. @SamCramphorn, to be clear, do you want to update the variable `@Ad1` or a column in Address table? If you want to update a column I would use a `CTE` or a `merge` statement.

Comment: Hi @MihailStancescu 

I want to update all the fields that `@ad1` contains, _In this instance_ I want all the blank information to contain _'BLANK'_ from `@adnew`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this in my SP:

```
update adr
    set adr.Ad1 = @AdNew
 from Address adr
 where adr.Ad1 = @Ad1
```

This will work assuming that Ad1 is a column in the Address table.

Comment: Great. 

this has been bugging me for ages now.